# Remove duplicate input fields with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates

I have six input fields where a user enters text strings. These strings cannot be identical so I need to warn the user as soon as duplicate  entries have been attempted. I have the following jQuery which nicely alert's the user when there has been duplicate entry. However, I'm trying to remove the input field that was the duplicate, and this code actually removes the first occurrence of the duplicated string. Is it possible to alert the user there has been a duplicate entry and also remove the correct duplicate input field? Thanks for your help

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control alldifferent" id="barcode0" name="barcode0" placeholder="barcode 1">
<input type="text" class="form-control alldifferent" id="barcode1" name="barcode1" placeholder="barcode 2">
<input type="text" class="form-control alldifferent" id="barcode2" name="barcode2" placeholder="barcode 3">
<input type="text" class="form-control alldifferent" id="barcode3" name="barcode3" placeholder="barcode 4">
<input type="text" class="form-control alldifferent" id="barcode4" name="barcode4" placeholder="barcode 5">
<input type="text" class="form-control alldifferent" id="barcode5" name="barcode5" placeholder="barcode 6">
```

jQuery:

```
 $(".alldifferent").keyup(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if (val != '') {
          $(".alldifferent").not(this).each(function() {
              if ($(this).val() == val) {
                  alert("Error, Duplicate Barcode " + val);
                  val = $(this).val('');
                  return false; // stop the loop
              }
          });
      }
  });
```

Fiddle: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/5d4wy3o0/)

Comment: *"I'm trying to remove the input field that was the duplicate"* - You mean that you want to clear the value from that field, not remove the input field itself, right? (And are you sure that keyup is the best event to use? "abc" and "abcde" are different values, but your code wouldn't let the user type "abcde" because it would stop them at "abc".)

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of this issue. however the user will be scanning this string using a USB barcode scanner so I don't think it should be an issue.. If you can think of an alternative solution I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: You can use keyup, but youll need a timer to avoid the issue @nnnnnn brings up

Answer (score 2):

Below is how I would do it. Note that I am binding to both `keyup` and `paste`. One of the  gothchas of `keyup` alone is that if the user uses the right click context menu to paste (hi grandpa), the event wont be fired. This fixes that. It also uses a timer to prevent the issue that nnnnnn alludes to in the comment above

#### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zneh024p/7/)

```js
// do this with a timer function so that it is called 400 ms after the user finishes typing 
// not after every keystroke which will often lead to annoying behaviour
$(".alldifferent").on('keyup paste',function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  keyupDelay(function() {
    var val = $this.val();
    $this.attr('value', val);
    if (val != '') {
      // get all inputs with this value and and index greater than 0 ( the duplicates ) setting all to ''
      var $dupes = $('input[value="' + val + '"]:gt(0)').val(''); 
      // if we had to empty any, alert the user
      if ($dupes.length > 0) alert('Duplicates are not allowed!');
    }
  }, 400);// delay, adjust as needed
});


// timer function to be used with keyup
var keyupDelay = (function() {
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control alldifferent" id="barcode0" name="barcode0" placeholder="barcode 1">
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control alldifferent" id="barcode1" name="barcode1" placeholder="barcode 2">
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control alldifferent" id="barcode2" name="barcode2" placeholder="barcode 3">
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control alldifferent" id="barcode3" name="barcode3" placeholder="barcode 4">
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control alldifferent" id="barcode4" name="barcode4" placeholder="barcode 5">
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control alldifferent" id="barcode5" name="barcode5" placeholder="barcode 6">
```

Comment: Excellent! exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @DelightedD0D

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, what I would do is add a tracker that keeps track of the input value to the original input, so that you can compare to see if that was the original one or not.

See here:

```
var tracker = {};
$(".alldifferent").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val != '') {
        $(".alldifferent").each(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            var thisval = input.val();

            // ignore empty values
            if (thisval.length === 0) return;

            // get the one being tracked
            var trackedInput = tracker[thisval];
            if (trackedInput && !input.is(trackedInput) && trackedInput.val() === thisval) {
                // if we get here, it means this input wasn't the first to have this value
                alert("Error, Duplicate Barcode " + thisval);
                input.val('');
                return;
            }

            // if we get here, it means this value is unique, so add it to the tracker
            tracker[thisval] = input;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: this removes the entire input field.. I need to clear the input field so user can  'try again'.. is that possible?

Comment: Ignoring the "remove" versus "clear" issue, this code has the same problem as the OP's code, in that it removes the wrong input.

Comment: yeah..insted of `.remove()` use `.val('')`

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to remove it from the DOM.  I've updated my answer for clearing an `input`.

Comment: @smaili have you tested this? because it gives me the same effect as my current code in the question.

Comment: Then I'm having a hard time understanding your requirements...can you try to give an example of the desired behavior?

Comment: Add two handlers, one on('keyup') to toggle error css class and another on('change') to clear/remove entries.

Comment: look at this fiddle, clearly demonstrates the issue https://jsfiddle.net/5d4wy3o0/

Comment: When 2 fields have the same field, how do you define which one is the duplicate?  Based on the order of the inputs?  So if input1 and input3 have the same value, input3 is the duplicate because it's after input1?

Comment: Thats correct, essentially once a user types in an input field it's saved, than any future inputs added cannot not be a duplicate of that, if it is than it prompts the user and clears the value of the input field.

Comment: You might remove all the clutter related to `.remove()` now that its clear thats not the issue

Comment: Ah much cleaner, though we should point out that this method will suffer from the same problem that nnnnnn mentioned in a comment on the question, namely **"abc" and "abcde" are different values, but your code wouldn't let the user type "abcde" because it would stop them at "abc"**, youd need a timer to fix that

Comment: Also, pasting with right click will defeat this check as it wont be fired

Comment: @DelightedD0D, yes but the OP had said that he's both aware and okay with putting that responsibility on the user.  So unless he decides to add additional requirements to his original question then I'd say my updated solution should suffice.  Regarding pasting, you're right but it's not that hard to refactor the solution into a function and have both events call the same helper.  But again, I'd say that will start to extend beyond the scope of the original question, which is tracking duplicates in `keyup`.

Comment: Apologies, I did not see where the OP had said that he's both aware and okay with putting that responsibility on the user.